# Why does my query work with 3 columns but fail with 4 or more?

Tags: php, sql

This query works:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pw");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("db", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO l1_clubmsg (msg, subject, status)
VALUES
(1,1,1)";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
```

But when i change:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO l1_clubmsg (msg, subject, status)
VALUES
(1,1,1)";
```

To:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO l1_clubmsg (msg, subject, status, to)
VALUES
(1,1,1,1)";
```

I get this error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 

MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to) VALUES (1,1,1,1)' at line 1
```

The 'to' column does exist in l1_clubmsg

Any ideas why this gets an error? thanks

Comment: what is the type of the 'to' column? compared to the other columns?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html "TO"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It not because of 4 or more columns that the error is produced.

The error is produced because `to` is a keyword and can't be used like this.

You can write the query as:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO l1_clubmsg (msg, subject, status, `to`)
VALUES
(1,1,1,1)";
```

For the list of keywords you could look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

**Note:** Normally try to avoid keywords in the query. And if you use make sure that you escape it using backticks(`)

Answer (score 5):

[`TO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) is a reserved word in mysql, so if you want to use it as a column name, you need to escape it like;

```
INSERT INTO l1_clubmsg (msg, subject, status, `to`) VALUES (1,1,1,1)
```

It's usually a good idea to escape all column and table names since newer versions of databases may have new reserved words, but in this case only one is required.

Answer (score 2):

`TO` is a reserved word in MySQL. You will have to escape it in your query. Try

```
$sql="INSERT INTO l1_clubmsg (msg, subject, status, `to`)
VALUES
(1,1,1,1)";
```

The punctuation marks I've added around to are called backticks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `to` is a reserved work in MySQL - you'll need to make sure that MySQL interprets correctly as a column name. Instead of:

```
INSERT INTO l1_clubmsg (msg, subject, status, to)
VALUES
(1,1,1,1)
```

Try:

```
INSERT INTO l1_clubmsg (`msg`, `subject`, `status`, `to`)
VALUES
(1,1,1,1)
```

The backticks ensure that it's parsed appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put quotation marks around `TO`.

Comment: Well, specifically, you have to put backticks around TO.  `'TO'` or `"TO"` won't work; it has to be `\`TO\``.

Comment: @MarkReed, as a side comment, double quotes would work under ANSI_QUOTES mode.